# Recursively print file length

Tags: text-processing, wc

How to print the length of all *.txt files in a directory?

Eg: Directory content:

```
FileA.txt 
FileB.txt
FileC.txt 
FileA.csv
```

*.txt length:

```
less FileA.txt | wc -l 
43
less FileB.txt | wc -l 
13
less FileC.txt | wc -l 
3
```

Desired output (write to output file):

```
43
13
3
```

(I am trying, with no success: `ls *.txt| while read FN; do wc -l < $FN >> output; done` - outputs empty file)

Comment: I do not see any recursion here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some alternatives:

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -sn '$=' ./*.txt
```

(note that it will not report the number for empty files, and (contrary to `wc -l`), will count spurious data after the last newline character as an extra line).

Wildcard patterns like `*.txt`, by default don't include hidden files.

With GNU `awk`:

```
awk 'ENDFILE{print FNR}' ./*.txt
```

This time, you'll get a `0` for empty files. Same note about spurious data as for GNU `sed`.

```
$ seq 10 > a.txt; : > b.txt; printf spurious > c.txt; seq 20 > .hidden.txt; echo test > $'a\n3 4.txt'
$ wc -l ./*.txt
 1 ./a
3 4.txt
10 ./a.txt
 0 ./b.txt
 0 ./c.txt
11 total
$ wc -l ./*.txt | awk '/\//{print $1}'
1
10
0
0
$ sed -ns '$=' ./*.txt
1
10
1
$ awk 'ENDFILE{print FNR}' ./*.txt
1
10
0
1
```

Recursively, if you want a list sorted by filename, with `zsh` or `ksh -o globstar` or `bash -O globstar` or `yash -o extended-glob`:

```
wc -l .//**/*.txt | awk '/\/\//{print $1}'
sed -ns '$=' ./**/*.txt
awk 'ENDFILE{print FNR}' ./**/*.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

```
wc -l -- *.txt
```

or if you don't want the filenames in the output (here assuming file names don't contain newline characters):

```
wc -l -- *.txt | awk '{print $1}'
```

If there are too many *.txt files to fit on a single shell command line and assuming your find supports `-maxdepth`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -exec wc -l {} + | 
    awk '$2 != "total" {print $1}'
```

(note that that one, contrary to the previous one will not sort the file list, will include hidden files and exclude non-regular files including symlinks to regular files).

You can, of course, redirect the output of any of these to a file or pipe it into another program for more processing.

Comment: Thanks! The `find`solution worked for me!

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - so it will, i forgot about that.  fixed.  slower but fixed.   `wc` really needs some extra options like `--no-total` and `--no-filenames`

Comment: fixed again, this time in awk.  back to being fast again.

Comment: Best is to look for the `/` (see my answer) to also avoid problems with filenames containing newline characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [wildcards](http://www.linfo.org/wildcard.html) in combination with [wc](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_wc.htm) command to get the number of lines of each file:

```
wc -l *.txt
```

The output will be as follows:

> 13 a.txt
>
> 29 b.txt
>
> 3 d.txt
>
> 45 total

If you dont wnat the total lines you can pipe it to the [head](http://www.linfo.org/head.html) command **provided you have more than one file to count**:

`wc -l *.txt |head -n -1`

If you want ony the number of line and not the file:

`wc -l *.txt |head -n -1 |awk '{print $1}'`

Alternately you can try with for loops to avoid the total count whether there is one file or more than one file ,but its the ugliest way:

`for i in $(ls *.txt);do wc -l $i;done`

Comment: The `total` line is only printed if there are more than 1 input files.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct.